# Unboxing of 'characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: camera, nullpointerexception

https://github.com/yabushi/TimeStampCamera

自分で書いた部分↓
https://github.com/yabushi/TimeStampCamera/blob/4b4c441675a6a5e7d6b2cf1f0448e19b1a115fd7/app/src/main/java/com/example/shigeki/timestampcamera/MainActivity.java

のプログラムをRUNしようとすると「Android端末には問題が発生したのでTimeStampCameraを終了します」と表示され、以下のエラーが出ます。

72行目の  `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)`の部分に問題がありそうだとは思いましたが、解決方法がわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera, PID: 867
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera/com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
        at com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:46)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: タイトルとされたメッセージはビルド時の警告であって、実行時の例外情報として出力されたものではないように思われるのですが?

Comment: はい、実行時の例外情報ではないです。　アプリが終了するのは他に原因があるということでしょうか。

Comment: 今回は、アプリの異常終了の原因は警告メッセージとは別でしょう。スタックトレースも例外メッセージもインスタンスの初期化中に例外が発生したことを示しています。`findViewById`がスタックトレース中に現れているので、一番怪しいのはそこ(`MainActivity.java:46`)でしょう。

Comment: 指摘いただいた部分をフィールドではなく変数として宣言してみたところ、その部分は解決したようです！ありがとうございます。

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.example.android.TimeStampCamera.TextureView

Comment: エラー内容が上記に変化したのですが、これは自分で書いたXMLレイアウトのTextureViewの箇所がおかしいという理解でよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 元のご質問内容とはまた別の問題点にはまっておられるようなので、新スレッドで新しい質問としていただいた方が良いでしょう。なお、このご質問の解決方法については、ご自身で「回答」として投稿(さらに「承認」も)していただくことで今後も多くの開発者の方に役立ちますので、お時間をお取りいただけるようお願いします。XMLレイアウトに関するエラーについての新質問を書かれる場合には、もう少しエラーに関する情報をお示しいただいた方が良いでしょう。今の情報だけでは「なんらかの形で`TextureView`に関連した部分がおかしい」としか言えません。XMLの問題かもしれませんし、`TextureView`クラスの定義に問題があるのかもしれません。

Comment: わかりました。別の質問として投稿させていただきます。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

元のプログラムはこれです。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////フィールド////////

    //CameraDeviceインスタンス用変数
    CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    //CameraCaptureSession用の変数
    CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession = null;

    //CaptureRequest用変数
    CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest = null;

    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;

        //画面にセットされたTextureView
        final TextureView mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.textureview);

        //シャッターボタン
        final Button ShutterButton = findViewById(R.id.shutter);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

mTextureViewとShutterButtonの定義位置を下記のように変更すると解決しました。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////フィールド////////

    //CameraDeviceインスタンス用変数
    CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    //CameraCaptureSession用の変数
    CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession = null;

    //CaptureRequest用変数
    CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest = null;

    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //画面にセットされたTextureView
        final TextureView mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.textureview);

        //シャッターボタン
        final Button ShutterButton = findViewById(R.id.shutter);
```